# Как можно обратиться к объекту ввода вывода в qdateTimeEdit по средствам stylesheets?

Tags: qt

Хочу добавить рамку как показал на картинки. Но не знаю как обратиться к объекту ввода вывода цифр (не знаю как правильно его назвать).

Вопрос как можно обратиться к объекту ввода вывода для добавления контура?

```
    QDateTimeEdit {
     padding-top: 20px; 
     padding-bottom: 20px; 

     border-image: url("/home/image/next.png");
     border-width: 0px;

     background-clip: content;
 }

 QDateTimeEdit::up-button {
     subcontrol-origin:   border;
     subcontrol-position: top center left center;
     top: 15px; 
     left: 20px;
     width: 16px;
     height:16px;
     border-image: url("/home/image/next_.png");
 }

 QDateTimeEdit::down-button {
     subcontrol-origin:  border;
     subcontrol-position: bottom center;
     width: 16px;
     height:16px;
 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Показал что хочу получить в итоги. Вот думаю можно с помощью stylesheets это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

для масштабируемого виджета - никак.

Весь виджет представляет из себя box-model https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model
т.е. при масштабировании растягивается content (при этом марджин/бордер/паддинг остаются фиксированными)

Если размер фиксирован, то подбирайте марджины

```
   QDateTimeEdit {
     margin-top: 40px; 
     margin-bottom: 40px; 
     padding-top: 1px; 
     background-origin: margin;
     background-image: url(":/new/img");
     background-clip: margin;
     border: 1px solid black;
 }

 QDateTimeEdit::up-button {
     subcontrol-origin:   margin;
     subcontrol-position: top center;
     top: -30px;
     width: 16px;
     height:16px;
 }

 QDateTimeEdit::down-button {
     subcontrol-origin:   margin;
     subcontrol-position: bottom center;
     bottom: -30px;
     width: 16px;
     height:16px;
 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вообще, учитывая количество ваших проблем с этим виджетом, я бы уже скомпоновал то что мне надо из нескольких отдельных виджетов

Comment: Tatarincev обновил вопрос. Показал на картинки, что хочу получить в вопросе.

Comment: Я уже описал, что ровно вокруг поля ввода рамку сделать невозможно. только подбирать margin если размеры виджета фиксированы. Грубо говоря весь виджет это один единый бокс со своими полями. сабконтрола с текстом нет. Либо как я советовал компонуйте из нескольких виджетов то что вы хотите получить, либо перегружайте resizeEvent, пересчитывайте margin "руками" и обновляйте stylesheet

Comment: Вы говорили, что можно сделать из нескольких виджетов это как?

Comment: см ниже. если надо, часть спейсеров фиксированного размера сделать

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Виджет

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <widget name="__qt_fake_top_level">
  <widget class="QFrame" name="frameWhole">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>570</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>351</width>
     <height>191</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>0</width>
     <height>100</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">#frameWhole{
     border-image: url(&quot;:/new/img&quot;)  0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
}</string>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShape">
    <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShadow">
    <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
   </property>
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_5">
    <property name="spacing">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item>
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>70</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
       <property name="spacing">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frameUp">
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
          <property name="spacing">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="rightMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>20</width>
              <height>10</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_4">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="ButtonUp">
              <property name="focusPolicy">
               <enum>Qt::NoFocus</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="styleSheet">
               <string notr="true">max-width: 40px;
max-height: 20px;</string>
              </property>
              <property name="text">
               <string>туда</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_5">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
          <item>
           <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>20</width>
              <height>10</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_6">
         <item>
          <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_10">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>40</width>
             <height>20</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QDateTimeEdit" name="dateTime">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>0</width>
             <height>16</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">   QDateTimeEdit {
     background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0% );
     border: 1px solid black;
 }
</string>
           </property>
           <property name="buttonSymbols">
            <enum>QAbstractSpinBox::NoButtons</enum>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_11">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>40</width>
             <height>20</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frameUp_2">
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
          <property name="spacing">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="rightMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <spacer name="verticalSpacer_3">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>20</width>
              <height>10</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_6">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="ButtonUp_2">
              <property name="focusPolicy">
               <enum>Qt::NoFocus</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="styleSheet">
               <string notr="true">max-width: 40px;
max-height: 20px;</string>
              </property>
              <property name="text">
               <string>туда</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_7">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
          <item>
           <spacer name="verticalSpacer_4">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>20</width>
              <height>10</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>69</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
</ui>
```

и обработчики на батоны типа такого

```
void MainWindow::on_ButtonUp_clicked()
{
    switch (ui->dateTime->currentSectionIndex()) {
          case 0:{ //day
              ui->dateTime->setDateTime(ui->dateTime->dateTime().addDays(1));
              break;
          }
          case 1:{ //month
              ui->dateTime->setDateTime(ui->dateTime->dateTime().addMonths(1));
              break;
          }
          case 2:{ //year
              ui->dateTime->setDateTime(ui->dateTime->dateTime().addYears(1));
              break;
          }
        // .... HH MM SS
    }
}
```